# How can i make my footer stick to bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

How can i make my footer stick to the bottom of the page with almost no content?

```
<footer>
<hr>
<p> &copy; 2017 Sindre Berge <p>
</footer>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Comment: See the official examples at https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/ and http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
<style> 
footer {
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center; /* This line is not needed but centers your text */
    }
</style>

<footer>
    <hr>
    <p> &copy; 2017 Sindre Berge <p>
</footer>
```

See it in action and play with it here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEO78PICTTQP

Or try the flex solution proposed by [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7733724/sam). This will not cause the footer to not always be at the bottom of the browser view but instead at the bottom of the page.

**Flex solution:**

```css
.flex-container {
   display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    /*I give height 700px but can be adapted to a body being 100%*/
    height:700px;
    background:#cccccc;
    }

.flex-content {
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
    background:#ca33aa;
    height:100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-content">
This is my footer
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do not set your z-index to 999. https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Hi, let me edit to add the flex solution then I remove my answer. I dont mind merits but I think it completes the info for users coming after. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

in CSS:

```
footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

or you could inline it:

```
<footer style="position:fixed; bottom:0; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
<hr>
<p> &copy; 2017 Sindre Berge <p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Okey both did what i wanted but its no longer centered i had footer p { text-align: center; }

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the centering of the text as you had before.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use

```
footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width: 99%;
}
```

as I've found that sometimes the site will go haywire -- especially as far as the `width` is concerned, as by itself I am sometimes greeted by a nasty horizontal scroll bar at the bottom, despite everything fitting onto the screen nicely.

Comment: You might want to look into why your page is adding the scrollbars when you don't want it to rather than simply arbitrarily changing the width.

Comment: It's just pure HTML and CSS, not a single script.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me, perhaps you have some margin, padding, or a border somewhere that's on an element with width at or around 100% already.

Comment: There is nothing left or right of the footer. There is text above but it's just plain text with some `em`s and hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

**Block solution:**

```
footer {
display:block;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

**Flex solution:**

```css
.flex-container {
   display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    /*I give height 700px but can be adapted to a body being 100%*/
    height:700px;
    background:#cccccc;
    }

.flex-content {
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
    background:#ca33aa;
    height:100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-content">
This is my footer
  </div>
  </div>
```